# Seguementation Fault (Core Dump) C

Tags: c, memory

I'm facing the issue segmentation fault. I know that is related with memory.
I did some changes but its keeps with error. I'm trying read a big file 25kb.
I need read a biggest csv and slip it in struct by line. I did it with linked list.
I already tried also with a list.
If I read the file without split the the string I dont have error.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



struct gh_user {
    char *id;
    char *login;
    char *type;
    char *createdat;
    char *followers;
    char *followerlist;
    char *following;
    char *followinglist;
    char *public_gists;
    char *pub_repos;
    struct gh_user *next;
};

typedef struct gh_user *GH_USER;

void separador (char *lines, GH_USER k) {

    k->id = strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->login = strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->type = strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->createdat = strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->followers = strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->followerlist = strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->following = strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->followinglist = strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->public_gists = strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->pub_repos = strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    free(lines);
}


int conta_bots()
{
    FILE *usr;
    usr = fopen("../entrada/users.csv","rb");
    
    
    int contador = 0;
    
    char *lines = malloc(1024);
    GH_USER k = malloc(sizeof(struct gh_user));
    int fileSize = 0;

    while (fgets(lines, 1024,usr)!=NULL)
    {  
    
    if(lines != NULL)
    {  
        separador (lines,k->next);
        printf("%s", k->type);
    }
    
    }
    free(k);
    fclose(usr);   
    free(lines);
    
    return contador;
}


int main()
{
    conta_bots();
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you share the debugger result?

Comment: Check if `fopen` returns `NULL`. The file might not exist. And please don't tell us "I'm sure the file exists".

Comment: There are other issues like: `if(lines != NULL)`: this check is pointless. `typedef struct gh_user *GH_USER;`: don't hide pointer types behind typedefs, it only causes confusion.

Comment: `separador (lines,k->next);` you never initialize `k->next` to anything, so the function is writing stuff to random memory somewhere.

Comment: if `strsep` does not find a delimiter (e.g. the last item on a line), it will set lines to NULL, so that free is `free(NULL)`. Not that free minds being handed a null pointer, but you may have a memory leak as well.

Comment: Actually freeing a pointer that was not malloced is undefined. `strsep` updates the value of `lines` to a different address than what it started with, and as a result `free(lines)` may exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: I correct it. But keeps the same error. separador (lines,k);
 printf("%s", k->type);
 k->next = calloc(1,sizeof(struct gh_user));
 k = k->next;

Comment: It would be best to use a debugger to find out at which line it falls over. If you have made changes to the code, please [edit] the code in your question and also update the observed behavior, if necessary.

Comment: If you have new code and/or new information, please **add** it to your question. Don't delete the old contents, because that would render comments and (possibly) answers useless.

Comment: @dratenik how did you implemented to check after each strsep the result to is NULL? Do an if after each  strdup(strsep(&lines, ";")); ?

Comment: If you're not inclined to run the debugger yourself, please share a representative bit of your csv that would allow us to reproduce the fault for ourselves. See also [mre].

Comment: strsep doesn't mind null, strdup does, so you could make a wrapper around strdup... `char * my_strdup(char * in) {return strdup(in?in:"");}` and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the data it is hard to say where exactly it crashed, but let's try to fix issues I can see without running the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct gh_user {
    char *id;
    char *login;
    char *type;
    char *createdat;
    char *followers;
    char *followerlist;
    char *following;
    char *followinglist;
    char *public_gists;
    char *pub_repos;
    struct gh_user *next;
};

char *n_strdup(char *in) {
    return strdup(in ? in : "");
}

void separador (char *lines, struct gh_user *k) {
    k->id = n_strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->login = n_strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->type = n_strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->createdat = n_strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->followers = n_strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->followerlist = n_strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->following = n_strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->followinglist = n_strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->public_gists = n_strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
    k->pub_repos = n_strdup(strsep(&lines, ";"));
}

/*yes, you need to free all that*/
void gh_user_free(struct gh_user *ptr) {
    if (!ptr) return;
    free(ptr->id);
    free(ptr->login);
    free(ptr->type);
    free(ptr->createdat);
    free(ptr->followers);
    free(ptr->followerlist);
    free(ptr->following);
    free(ptr->followinglist);
    free(ptr->public_gists);
    free(ptr->pub_repos);
    free(ptr);
}


int conta_bots()
{
    FILE *usr;
    usr = fopen("../entrada/users.csv","rb");

    int contador = 0;

    char lines[1024];

    while (fgets(lines, 1024,usr)!=NULL)
    {  
        struct gh_user *k = calloc(1, sizeof(struct gh_user));
        separador (lines,k);
        printf("%s", k->type);
        gh_user_free(k);
    }
    fclose(usr);
    
    return contador; /*possibly that var was supposed to be updated in some way?*/
}


int main()
{
    conta_bots();
    return 0;
}
```

Your code sample makes no use of the linked list, so I omitted that.